# how can I embed animation graphs generated in R using plotly into a powerpoint presentation on macbook?

Tags: r, macos, animation, powerpoint, embed

I've generated an animated scatterplot which is running fine on when exported in my workspace, however I wonder how this graph can be imported in an existing powerpoint presentation while keeping the animation working, i.e. not as an png file?

Comment: powerpoint supports animaged gif, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a plotly plot in R markdown and present the slides using the [revealjs](https://github.com/rstudio/revealjs) package in R.

Check out an example of code to generate revealjs slides with plotly [here](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/98#issue-286662745).